# What is a good alternative to email archive appliances for MS Exchange?

Tags: exchange-2010, archive, barracuda, email

I'm currently using a Barracuda Networks Message Archiver 350 appliance for email archiving (since 2008). I've been updating the Barracuda firmware as soon as a new version is released.

The Barracuda appliance ran out of space this year and I started using external storage.  Some of the archive is stored on the appliance and another part of it is stored on a network shared drive.

Recently, after the latest firmware version was installed, the Barracuda appliance 
started showing 100% CPU usage and 100% memory usage.

I got on the phone with Barracuda support and they remoted into the Barracuda 
appliance and rebuilt the archive.

The problem was that I had a 15 day junk email retention policy and every day 
when junk emails emails older than 15 days would be deleted, the whole archive 
would get re-indexed. This re-indexing would cause the 100% CPU usage and 100% memory usage.

Barracuda support just changed the junk email retention policy so that  junk emails are stored but not deleted after 15 days (so the deletion 
event does not cause a complete re-index process)

Now, junk emails are just continually stored on the shared drive and never 
get deleted which is not really a good solution.

This hack is working, but Barracuda support is stating that the hardware is 
too old and that I should upgrade to the latest and greatest appliance (which 
costs approximately $7,000)  Apparently the appliance I have is too slow (CPU), 
it does not have enough memory and storage. I can not upgrade the appliance memory 
or storage as doing so would void the support agreement.

I don't want to buy the latest and greatest Barracuda appliance now. 
Moreover, in 5 years, when the latest and greatest Barracuda appliance is 
obsolete, I don't want to buy the latest and greatest Barracuda appliance. 
If I buy a new appliance now, in 2012, then I'd have to buy the latest and 
greatest Barracuda appliance of 2017 after the 2012 hardware no longer 
"cuts it".

I don't want to use Exchange 2010 pst personal archiving because to search
a pst archive it needs to be moved/copied across the network.

Is there an email archiving solution that I can use on a commodity server (Linux or Windows) that will archive and index all incoming and outgoing emails (a 500 GB archive)?

I'm open to proprietary and OSS solutions.

Comment: Product or service recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: We don't do shopping recommendations.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: It's a real problem, and perhaps this question could be worded differently. I answered just to be able to share my experience.

Comment: Just worded question differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just stick a linux server in-line with an MTA of your choice? It would be trivially easy to have sendmail, postfix, etc. archive locally then relay to the Exchange server?

Comment: Had not thought of a man-in-the-middle Linux relay. That's a excellent idea!

Comment: But you still need the GUI and a search interface. That's where a proper journaling solution comes in.

Comment: @ewwhite **Need** a GUI? SACRILEGE! Real men use `grep`. ;)

Comment: @ErikA A nice GUI would get my manager to buy in. Also, grep is a sequential-search tool. It's like having to do a full-file scan instead of using b-tree indexes. I like build-once, self-balancing indexes. You get fast range scans and searches with indexes.

Comment: @DragosToader - of course. I understand the convenience and usability factor of a well-engineered solution. My comment was (mostly) in jest. Though to be honest, you didn't list a GUI as a requirement in your question.

Comment: @ErikA - Psssh. GREP. Typically, we journal mail for HR/legal/compliance/regulatory reasons. It's nice to be able to allow auditors or other staff craft complex queries in something like MailArchiva and get at the data they need quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I STRONGLY recommend [MailArchiva Enterprise](https://www.mailarchiva.com/enterprisebenefits) as an Exchange journaling solution. It's great for other mail servers as well. For Exchange, it pulls via IMAP to a dedicated journal user. The process for setup is easy and well-documented.

The main features mail deduplication/compression, search engine quality indexing/retrieval, encryption and portability. This needs to run on its own server, but that's no different than having a separate Barracuda device. You have control over the hardware and solution at this point. MailArchiva is Java-based and runs in Windows or Linux. I run it on Linux and have made it through several SEC audits and countless message retrieval sessions.

There's a free version, but the commercial version has a much better interface and may have been ~$3k for 100 users.

The lesson here is also that Barracuda's practices and hardware are rough...